# Quantum NN vs Quantum-Inspired NN

Tags: quantum-gate, machine-learning, neural-network

I can't find the true difference between Quantum Neural Network (QNN) and Quantum-Inspired Neural Network (QINN).

I have multiple guesses:

1. QINN and QNN are absolutely the same thing (all QNNs are actually QINNs unless the true quantum computing hardware is developed)
2. QINNs are the neural nets ensembles.
3. Something else.?

Thank you a lot for any information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A QNN is a "quantum implementation of a NN" that actually runs on a quantum device. 
Look for example at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12486) by Tacchino et al.

A QINN instead is a complex model that runs on traditional hardware (maybe special-purpose, but still classical).

For quantum vs. quantum inspired computing, look at this [white paper](http://marketing.us.fujitsu.com/rs/407-MTR-501/images/quantum-inspired-computing.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for answer!